# Issue in extended display setup for C# WPF Application (Combobox)

Tags: c#, wpf, display

I have a dual monitor setup. When I open my application on a primary monitor and drag it to secondary monitor (in mid of both) and open the combo box that's in the app, it opens up on a primary monitor even though the application is moved to the secondary monitor.

[Please find image which having both primary and secondary screens](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wDpOe.jpg)

Combo box is on primary screen and after mouse click list box open in secondary screen

Please let me know if you know a fix for this.
Thank you in advance.

I am clueless here.

Comment: It is because the window belongs to the right monitor. The logic of placement is implemented in Popup and If you don't like it in any circumstance, ComboBox may not be the right choice for you.

Answer (score 1):

The `Popup` is actually a real `Window`. It is associated with the primary scree on which it was created (implicitly, by the `ComboBox`). That's why the `Popup` in general behaves "strange" when you open it and start to move the placement target. The `Popup` won't follow. It's not designed to follow the placement target. It is an independent "flying" window design with a very specific scenario in mind where a common Windo (or dialog) won't solve this problem. Usually, you open it for quick actions or briefly showing information (tool tip) and close it immediately when done, at least when moving the focus away. If you need a persistent window like a toolbox, then would use a dialog window. The point is that the `Popup` doesn't follow the placement target and therefore doesn't care about associated display changes.
You can force the `Popup` to update its location by changing a positioning property, for example the `Popup.HorizontalOffset` property.
For example:

```cs
HorzontalOffset +=1; 
HorizontalOffset -=1;
```

This should move the `Popup` to the new screen. You can for example implement an attached behavior that modifies the offset when the hosting `Window` moves. It's worth a try.
But note that in terms of `Popup` placement the type has certain edge cases. For example, if the Popup doesn't fit the screen, because it would clip the edge, the placement instructions are ignored, and the next position is chosen that allows the full display of the Popup. Clipping the boundaries in a multi-screen setup is such an edge case.
I can provide the following behavior for a try out. To attach it you would have to reference the actual `Popup` element. To do this you can override the original [`ControlTemplate`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/controls/combobox-styles-and-templates?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8#combobox-controltemplate-example) of the `ComboBox`.

## Usage

```xml
<Popup PopupService.IsSticky="True" />
```

**PopupService.cs**

```cs
public class PopupService : DependencyObject
{
#region IsFollowPlacementTargetPositionEnabled attached property
  
  public static readonly DependencyProperty IsStickyProperty =
    DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
      "IsSticky",
      typeof(bool),
      typeof(PopupService),
      new PropertyMetadata(default(bool), PopupService.OnIsStickyChanged));

  public static void SetIsSticky(DependencyObject attachingElement, bool value) 
    =>
    attachingElement.SetValue(PopupService.IsStickyProperty, value);

  public static bool GetIsSticky(DependencyObject attachingElement) 
    =>
    (bool)attachingElement.GetValue(PopupService.IsStickyProperty);

#endregion

  private static Dictionary<Window, IList<System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.Popup>> WindowToPopupsMap { get; set; }

  static PopupService() 
    => PopupService.WindowToPopupsMap = new Dictionary<Window, IList<System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.Popup>>();

  private static void OnIsStickyChanged(
    DependencyObject attachingElement,
    DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
  {
    if (attachingElement is not System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.Popup popup)
    {
      throw new ArgumentException("Attaching element must be of type 'System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.Popup'");
    }

    bool isEnabled = (bool)e.NewValue;

    if (isEnabled)
    {
      if (!popup.IsLoaded)
      {
        popup.Loaded += PopupService.EnableFollowTargetMovementOnPopupLoaded;
        return;
      }

      PopupService.EnableFollowTargetMovement(popup);
    }
    else
    {
      PopupService.DisableFollowTargetMovement(popup);
    }
  }

  private static void EnableFollowTargetMovementOnPopupLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) 
    => PopupService.EnableFollowTargetMovement(sender as System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.Popup);

  private static void EnableFollowTargetMovement(System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.Popup popup)
  {
    Window window = PopupService.GetParentWindow(popup);
    if (PopupService.WindowToPopupsMap.TryGetValue(window, out IList<System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.Popup> popups)
      && popups != null
      && !popups.Contains(popup))
    {
      popups.Add(popup);
    }
    else
    {
      PopupService.WindowToPopupsMap.Add(window, new List<System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.Popup>() { popup });
    }

    WeakEventManager<Window, EventArgs>.AddHandler(
      window,
      nameof(Window.LocationChanged),
      PopupService.UpdatePopup_OnParentWindowMoved);

    WeakEventManager<Window, SizeChangedEventArgs>.AddHandler(
      window,
      nameof(FrameworkElement.SizeChanged),
      PopupService.UpdatePopup_OnParentWindowSizeChanged);
  }

  private static void DisableFollowTargetMovement(System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.Popup popup)
  {
    Window window = PopupService.GetParentWindow(popup);
    if (PopupService.WindowToPopupsMap.TryGetValue(window, out IList<System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.Popup> popups)
        && !popups.Contains(popup))
    {
      _ = popups.Remove(popup);
      if (!popups.Any())
      {
        _ = PopupService.WindowToPopupsMap.Remove(window);
      }
    }

    WeakEventManager<Window, EventArgs>.RemoveHandler(
      window,
      nameof(Window.LocationChanged),
      PopupService.UpdatePopup_OnParentWindowMoved);

    WeakEventManager<Window, SizeChangedEventArgs>.RemoveHandler(
      window,
      nameof(FrameworkElement.SizeChanged),
      PopupService.UpdatePopup_OnParentWindowSizeChanged);
  }

  private static Window GetParentWindow(System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.Popup popup)
  {
    if (popup.PlacementTarget == null || !popup.PlacementTarget.TryFindVisualParentElement(out Window window))
    {
      window = Application.Current.MainWindow;
    }

    return window;
  }

  private static void UpdatePopup_OnParentWindowMoved(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    var window = sender as Window;
    PopupService.UpdatePopupPosition(window);
  }

  private static void UpdatePopup_OnParentWindowSizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
  {
    var window = sender as Window;
    PopupService.UpdatePopupPosition(window);
  }

  private static void UpdatePopupPosition(Window window)
  {
    if (PopupService.WindowToPopupsMap.TryGetValue(window, out IList<System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.Popup> popups))
    {
      foreach (var popup in popups)
      {
        popup.HorizontalOffset += 1;
        popup.HorizontalOffset -= 1;
      }
    }
  }
}
```